# React Native MapView in ScrollView Scrolling Error

Tags: android, ios, react-native, google-maps, scrollview

I do iOS and Android development with React Native. I use ScrollView because there are too many components on the page I'm working on. And all my components are inside this ScrollView.

```
package.json

"react": "17.0.2"
"react-native": "0.67.2"
"react-native-maps": "^0.30.1"
```

One of these components is the  component. I have not encountered such a problem while working on Android. But when I switch to the iOS side, when I scroll on the page, it automatically throws me down or up according to the action I make. There is no smooth scrolling. The page jumps up or down all of a sudden. In addition, there are ScrollViews with horizontal scrolling inside this page. In the same way, they jump to the bottom, the top or a certain distance. The same thing happens when I want to navigate in the map section. However, even if I block all accesses within the MapView, these jumps still occur.

```
<MapView
  pointerEvents="none"
  zoomEnabled={false}
  scrollEnabled={false}
  pitchEnabled={false}
  rotateEnabled={false}
  provider={MapView.PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
  ...
<MapView>
```

I just call the MapView component and put the necessary lng lat values ​​in it.

Just to be sure, I deleted the MapView component from the page and everything worked correctly. I never understood what to do.

Test Video: https://gifyu.com/image/SLqw7